# Maintain HTML comments in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Basically I have HTML comments in my XSLT that I want to preserve in the output but XSLT keeps dropping them. They are totally removed. Any way to keep these comments?

Below is a code example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

   <!-- Preserve This HTML Comment In Output -->
   <div><xsl:value-of select="xmlnode" /></div>

</xsl:template>
```

I've tried wrapping in `<xsl:text>` and `<xsl:comment>` tags but no help.

Comment: "*I have HTML comments in my XSLT.*" No, you have XML comments in your XSLT. And you cannot "preserve" them, because XSLT processes the XML input, not itself (though in theory you *could* copy the comment nodes from the XSLT document - but I wouldn't recommend going that way).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here/ It helped me understand what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining XML comments during XSL Transformations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703900/maintaining-xml-comments-during-xsl-transformations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't preserve comment but you can generate them in output with:

```
  <xsl:comment>This is a comment!</xsl:comment>
```

Therefor try

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <!-- Preserve This HTML Comment In Output -->
  <xsl:comment>Preserve This HTML Comment In Output</xsl:comment> 
  <div><xsl:value-of select="xmlnode" /></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Gotcha, so are you saying there is no way to output HTML comments using XSLT?

Comment: No comments in xlst will never appear in output. But you can generate comments in output.

Comment: Any reason this wouldn't work? It's not coming through.

Comment: It's working now. Without going into detail it was my code. Spot on thanks!

Comment: @hr_117: isn't passing through comments as an explict node `comment()` left at the discretion of the XSLT parser? I'm sure W3C mentioned that somewhere (and, from memory, also stated one should not count on it).

Comment: @RadLexus: you are right it  *isn't passing through comments*.  But it shouldn't. The question was how to “keep“ comments from xslt in output. Therefore https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Comments and **not comment()**.